# How to set checkbox selected on the basis of model value

Tags: angularjs

I have a checkbox and the value of this checkbox is fixed as 'A'. I want the checkbox selected if the model value matches with checkbox value attribute.

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <label class="col-md-2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Animals" name="Animals" ng-model="ModelData.Animals" value="A" /> Animal(s)
    </label>
</div>
```

But using the above code, checkbox selection is not working automatically. How can I achieve this?

Comment: From my point of view this will always be the same, because as soon as you bind ng-model to the input, the value is binded to the scope variable

Comment: I want to show this checkbox selected when ng-model has the value 'A'. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, try to use: `ng-checked="ModelData.Animals == 'A'"`

More information about ng-checked:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChecked

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ng-checked` directive to check it with an expression.

Here is a working example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BLWm/)

Comment: wrong fiddle link I guess, this is a `Hello, Superhero!` example ;)

Comment: Sorry, did a mess with the fiddles, fixed the link