# using angularjs checkbox is not updating after ajax call

Tags: angularjs

I have this checkbox

```
          <input type="checkbox" 
          ng-change="defaultMsgsHandler(vuser.use_managed_default_msgs)" 
          ng-model="vuser.use_managed_default_msgs" 
          ng-true-value=1 ng-false-value=0>
```

When i make this ajax call, the checkbox does not reflect the ajax retured has vuser.use_managed_default_msgs set to 1, but the checkbox is not checked. I know the model is correct. vuser.use_managed_default_msgs is a 1 if i dump vuser to the console.

```
    messageServices.getMessageSettingsInfo(user.dir)
                    .then(function(data) {
                        if (!data.success) {
                            $scope.errormessage = data.errors;
                        } else {
                            $scope.vuser = data.vuser;
                            $scope.messages = data.messages;
                        }
                    }, function(error) {
                        alert(error);
                    });
```

If i click on the checkbox defaultMsgsHandler changed the model correctly, and the checkbox checks and unchecks.

```
    $scope.defaultMsgsHandler = function( use_managed_default_msgs ){
        $scope.vuser.use_managed_default_msgs = use_managed_default_msgs;
    };
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried using $scope.$apply()?

Comment: Can we see an example of what data.vuser looks like when it is returned from the promise?  I believe that is where the problem is.

Comment: Cannot reproduce ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/LqCD349a3DAnk4d4XgpY?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Please, try to use: ng-checked="condition"

There is a similar question here,

[How to set checkbox selected on the basis of model value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703244/how-to-set-checkbox-selected-on-the-basis-of-model-value)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help, but I think your

```
ng-true-value=1 ng-false-value=0
```

should be

```
ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0"
```

Comment: I thought the same but it doesn't appear to make a difference.

Comment: unless your ajax response is returning a string not an integer, so it so would be `ng-true-value="'1'"`

Comment: Ah, great pickup. I just tried that and yes, if the value is a string it doesn't match the *true* value. Quoting the `ng-true-value` attribute values doesn't change that though

Comment: the string '' did the trick if in database the value is  not an integer